# Is there a means of USB interfacing to an iphone, which does not require an expensive Apple approval process?

Tags: usb, iphone

I am developing an external hardware that needs to make USB interface to iPhone. (30pins for now).

I do not think Apple would approve MFi for an individual.

For USB interface, is there no way? Or any kind of breakout board and protocol available?

Comment: I believe there's a USB-serial cable on the market if that would work.  Or you may have to do an Android version first to attract funding.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by USB interfacing? Will your device act as usb-peripheral (you want the iphone to control it, which it is very limited in doing) or usb-host (pretend it's a computer)? Are you just tapping it for power or what exactly?

Comment: If you aren't locked in to USB and have limited throughput needs, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) may be an option to explore, as this does not require partnership with Apple in the way that traditional bluetooth did.

Comment: It is not only power but USB peripheral where data transmissions are required.

Comment: @Chris Stratton If BLE does not require any approval process, then I would try it to prove functionality of my board and to attract funding.  Thanks.

Comment: If you can jailbreak, you can probably make it work. Some kernel hacking may be required, though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two ways to sneak around the Apple MFi approval

- Bluetooth communication
- Communication through the mic/earphone jack

Answer (score -2):

It seems that Apple, in order to provide maximum robustness for the users of their  OSes ( and possibly other, more nefarious, closed-door reasons ) has decided to make everyone jump through hoops to get **any integration with anything** working.  good for their customer in terms of public perception of stability of their OS, but bad for their developer ecology.  but it's their strategy, and developers must deal.

My answer is not really answering your question directly, but I hope to prevent you from going on a further wild goose chase, when powerful forces are working to prevent what you are trying to accomplish.

for goodness sakes, the IPad doesn't even have a USB port.  i asked the salesperson in the store about it, and he said USB drives were 'archaic' and 'the iCloud is better'.  the point is , if this is the company line vis a vis compatibility, good luck.

EDIT

Apple does have capability of accessing USB devices, but said USB interface is extremely limited, only works with some devices, and is restricted to viewing only 'image' type file on external file systems.  Prognosis: not looking good for getting it working with 'external hardware'.

Comment: iPAD does have a USB port. It is possible to purchase (eBay) adapters that plug into the iPADs connector and expose additional USB ports like a USB hub does that then in turn have standard USB connectors. Other adapters use the iPAD USB port to support memory card readers and external USB media devices.

Comment: @MichaelKaras does this equipment help move closer to the OPs request?

Comment: @AndyzSmith Michael's information is important to note that the ipad has usb otg capabilities.

Comment: @AndyzSmith - My comment was aimed squarely at your statement that "for goodness sakes, the IPad doesn't even have a USB port".

Comment: @MichaelKaras right, thanks, because i was only aware of the Camera Connection Kit and an associated kludge to get iOS to show it's file system under the auspices of moving pictures from a camera.  i'd be interested to know how complete/standardized the support for iOS capabilities the aforementioned USB peripherals expose.

Comment: This is neither an answer, nor fully accurate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton   so, the answer is NO, you cannot connect arbitrary , third party device, through USB to iPad. NO, there is no breakout board. NO there is no protocol.  please vote and give reasons ( and counterexample ) why you vote.

Comment: But that's not what you wrote in your "answer" - instead of saying that, you said other things which aren't fully true.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes , i did. i mention explicitly that my answer doesn't directly address the existence of such devices, but that based on my knowledge of Apple, such devices are extremely unlikely to exist, and therefore, by extension, the answer is no, you can't , and I can't give an example of how you **CAN**, because you can't.

Comment: in this situation, looking for a something that may not exist, characterization and educated best guesses are the best you can do.  because there is not going to be a specific, working, exmple.

Comment: You asked for a vote and now you got it; replace the somewhat inaccurate parts ("any integration with anything" and about the USB) of your answer with the more accurate things you've said in comments, and it might change.

Comment: also, **please give reason and counter example!** or at least, counter characteriztion , eg, 'Apple loves to interoperate with everything, it should be easy to do, get the SDK and RTFM'

Comment: Please re-read the entire page of this question to see the points that everyone else has raised and then either revise your "answer" to be an actual and accurate answer, or remove it in favor of making a comment.

Comment: i don't see any reason to backpedal on 'jump through hoops to integrate with anything'.  it does have pitiful USB support, which i mentioned and supports my answer.

Comment: @andyzSmith The usb port on the iPad allows for keyboards, sd cards, flash drives, usb audio and microphones, usb transfer from iphones or ipods, and usb hubs. For the most part, it is a full functioning OTG port, the only limitation being iOS DRIVERS for more stuff. And it also works on the iPhone.

Comment: ...Let's get it easy.  Thanks for opinions.
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/how-to-get-started-with-interfacing-usb-devices-to-ipad
It all started from trying to do that is not official way.